# GDM doesn't start after plymouth (bootsplash) and returns to grub - Debian on a Oracle Virtualbox VM

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, gdm

Each time when I start this VM with Debian I can't able to reach the GDM screen to make the login, instead of it, when the machine is initialized on grub it goes to the plymouth and after that it returns to grub and this cycle keeps on, I already went to the Live CD initializing the VM with a storage device (iso) and pressed F2 to turn the boot from the CD and at the Live mode I have tried to perform some `fsck` commands but nothing done.

I have in this VM some important tasks that I was doing and I stucked how to solve it and recover data from this VM, and this issue happened after few tests that I was doing adding users.